# How to open a tab containing the provided string in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension for Visual Studio Code, and I want to open a new tab containing some text I'll provide. I thought of using `vscode.window.showTextDocument` but it takes a `TextDocument` as input and I can't find how to create a `TextDocument` from a provided string. Any help?

Comment: Is this meant to be read-only text?  If so, consider using a TextDocumentContentProvider instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe VSCode allows the creation of [TextDocuments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#TextDocument) from strings.  One way of obtaining a TextDocument is to create a temporary file from the provided string, possibly in your extensions directory so that the user isn't bothered by it, and then use the [openTextDocument](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace) method on the file, which would return a TextDocument.

Comment: I ended up saving the file to `/tmp` using the `fs` module and then opening it  using `openTextDocument()`. Thanks.